# tae-kwon-do and shito ryo karate practice together

Tags: tae-kwon-do

I am a student of standard 12 and my age is 17. I have been practising shito ryo karate for 6 months; I am very much interested in taekwondo. May I practice both taekwondo and the shito ryo karate together?

Comment: I'm fairly certain most of the answers to this question are going to be similar to the answers to this other question: http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4865/pursuing-tae-kwon-do-and-karate-at-same-time